# TailwindCSS to exactly overlay two same-sized images and have them scale the same

Tags: tailwind-css

I have two images that are exactly the same size that I wish to overlay one on top of the other (in the z-direction) and have them:

1. Fit inside the containing divs (if that makes sense, e.g. a header), and
2. scale exactly the same way when their containing divs scales.

Something like having a logo in a header and as the page narrows it should scale, except that now there are two images.

Apologies if my terminology is not right there.

I have something like:

```
<div class="inline-block">
   <img src="/i1.png" class="XXX" />
    <img src="/i2.png" class="XXX absolute top-0 left-0" />
</div>
```

but don't know what to put in the XXX. I have tried h-full, w-full, w-fit,... and many combinations without success.

I basically just want them to behave as one image...

I would like to do it in TailwindCSS, please.

Thanks in advance,
Ashley.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need any other classes for the `<img>` elements, but you would need to apply `position: relative` on the `<div>` parent so that `top: 0` and `left: 0` will be relative to the parent container:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="inline-block relative">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1080" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1080?0" class="absolute top-0 left-0" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Wongjn that works great but the images are larger than the containing divs (e.g. header space). Is there a way I can also say for them to fit within their containing div(s)?

Comment: Yes, I would say there probably is a way.